# are Code Reviews for Functions/sprocs/etc. acceptable questions here?

Tags: discussion

I don't see very many review questions for SQL on CodeReview.StackExchange.com and was wondering if I should be posting them here instead?  I haven't posted any yet, but would like to know if that is the kind of thing that should be posted here.

Please Forgive if this is a Duplicate question.

I am not an Expert, but you have to learn somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have no issues with your code and would just like someone to take a look, then that, in my opinion, is definitely a question for Code Review.

Questions on this site, on the other hand, should have to do with some real problems you are experiencing, like code doesn't work, or it works incorrectly, or is too slow etc. (Please note also that [*not any* SQL question would be on topic here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

There may not be many SQL questions on Code Review but [there certainly are some](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql). So, as long as yours is a working piece of code, posting your question there would be perfectly fine.

Comment: so if there are issues with the code, then post it here, otherwise post it here?  the slow part can kind of go both ways, because it works but is slow, thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I agree that questions about slow code may qualify both here and on CR. Note, however, that I didn't say "slow", I said "too slow", meaning the slowness becomes a problem that needs solving, not just something that you wouldn't mind improve if possible. If it's the latter, that is not a really an issue and so the question is more for CR than for here, in my view. And if the slowness *is* a problem, you may also need to have an idea of how much faster you want it, before posting your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time in answering this question for me.